# How to vertically center the \vdots in this node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I'd like the `\vdots` in this chain to have the same distance to both of the arrows. I know that I could manually shift the node so that it looks right, but there must be a better solution. How?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,every join/.style={->}]
    \node [on chain, join] {A};
    \node [on chain, join] {$\vdots$};
    \node [on chain, join] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`\vdots` has been designed for matrices. You can use a modified version that doesn't add space at its top:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,every join/.style={->}]
    \node [on chain, join] {A};
    \node [on chain, join] {\rvdots};
    \node [on chain, join] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is brilliant! Would it be possible to do something similar for \ddots ?

Comment: @TedBlack Copy the definition of `\ddots` and remove `\kern 7\p@`

Comment: Thanks @egreg this is great help. By the way, there is a way of defining custom diagonal dots with tikz (for people like me who struggle understanding TeX code :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Try rotating the `\cdots`.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,every join/.style={->}]
    \node [on chain, join] {A};
    \node [on chain, join] {\rotatebox{90}{$\cdots$}};
    \node [on chain, join] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]