# How could I center the text in a rectangle split node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use TikZ to create pictures in LaTeX. My picture consists of a rectangle with nine split parts. Every part has its own text inside the node, for example, "local variables, and temporaries":

```
\nodepart{eight} \structtwenty Saved registers, local variables, and temporaries
```

My problem is the text is not centered in the node, but on top and bottom of the node, can any help, below is the whole TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\def\structforty{\vrule depth 4cm width 0pt} 
\def\structsix{\vrule depth 0.14cm width 0pt} 
\def\struceleven{\vrule depth 1.1cm width 0pt} 
\def\strucfourteen{\vrule depth 1.1cm width 0pt} 
\def\structtwenty{\vrule depth 1.9cm width 0pt} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  rect/.style={
    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=9,
    draw,rectangle split part align=center,draw, thick,
    text width=3cm,
    text centered, %minimum height=26em,
    % font=\ttfamily,
    align=center, rectangle split part align={center,left},
    rectangle split part align=midway,
    rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, blue!15, blue!20,blue!15,blue!15,green!15,green!20,green!30}
  }]

  \node (stack) [rect] {
\nodepart {one}\structforty $\vdots$
\nodepart {two}\struceleven $\vdots$

\nodepart{three}\structsix Argument n
\nodepart{four} \struceleven $\vdots$
\nodepart{five} \structsix Argument 1
\nodepart{six} \structsix Return Address
\nodepart{seven} \structsix Saved \%ebp
\nodepart{eight} \structtwenty Saved registers, local variables, and temporaries
\nodepart{nine} \strucfourteen Argument build area
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, welcome. Did you really need `\struct...`? If you remove them, it will work. You can define the vertical spacing with `inner ysep=`.

Comment: @cacamailg wouldn't `inner ysep` apply to all parts of the node? Apparently the OP wants to have each part with a different vertical spacing between the border and the contents.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `inner sep` applies to all. I said that because I didn't understand that @vampire wanted different vertical spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the node content, you can use a `\parbox` with centered alignment and predefined width and height; the \Textbox command receives two arguments:

```
\Textbox{<length>}{<text>}
```

where `<lenght>` is any valid length that lets you specify the height for the box, and `<text>` is the content for the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\newlength\Textwd
\setlength\Textwd{3cm}
\newcommand\Textbox[2]{%
  \parbox[c][#1][c]{\Textwd}{\centering#2}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
rect/.style={
  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=9,
  draw, thick,
  text width=3cm,
  text centered,
  rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, blue!15, blue!20,blue!15,blue!15,green!15,green!20,green!30}
}]

\node (stack) [rect] {
\nodepart {one} \Textbox{1cm}{$\rvdots$}
\nodepart {two} \Textbox{1cm}{$\rvdots$}
\nodepart{three} \Textbox{1.5cm}{Argument n}
\nodepart{four} \Textbox{1cm}{$\rvdots$}
\nodepart{five} \Textbox{1.5cm}{Argument 1}
\nodepart{six} \Textbox{1cm}{Return Address}
\nodepart{seven} \Textbox{1cm}{Saved \%ebp}
\nodepart{eight} \Textbox{3cm}{Saved registers, local variables, and temporaries}
\nodepart{nine} \Textbox{2cm}{Argument build area}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of the standard `\vdots` command, I used the version `\rvdots` from the  answer to [How to vertically center the \vdots in this node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112204/3954) to avoid some additional spacing at the top included by default in `\vdots`.

Comment: The `\rvdots` macro from [How to vertically center the \vdots in this node?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112204) might come in handy.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel indeed! I've added it to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You can redefine the `\textbox` command to set a default width.

Comment: Other way to have centralized vertical dots is to use the `ellipsis` package and add in the preamble `\newcommand\rvdots{\rotatebox{90}{\dots}}`.

Comment: @cacamailg I don't understand your first comment; `\textbox` has a fixed width that can be changed using `\Textwd`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina you are right, my fault :)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina one more quesstion, in my documnet I set the linespread to 2 globally, but it is too much for the box, so I set it to 1 in the parbox, bu it does not work. \parbox[c][#1][c]{\Textwd}{\linespread{1}\centering#2}}

Comment: @vampire Instead of manually setting `\linespread`, load the `setspace` package (`\usepackage{setspace}`) in the preamble and use `\doublespacing` in your preamble. Enclose the `tikzpicture` inside a `singlespace` environment: `\begin{singlespace}\begin{tikzpicture}[]...\end{tikzpicture}\end{singlespace}`

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina It works great, thank you so so much:)

Answer (score 1):

A TikZ-only alternative of Gonzalo Medina’s answer that uses the internal (with `text width` set already present) `\pgfutil@minipage` which is—in LaTeX—simply let to `\minipage` and therefore similar to `\parbox`.

There also did exist an alternative that adds a `\vrule` to `\tikz@textfont` (which is set by the `/tikz/font` key). That worked well for one-liners but not for the nodes with more than one line because the internal `minipage` is `t`op-aligned so a fix that uses `c` has been needed anyway. In addition to that, the first node part (`one` or `text`) seemed a little bit reluctant to the vertical alignment (I lost track because the original `\vdots` macro also messes with the vertical spacing).

There also exists a `heights` key so the heights can be set in advance.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
\tikzset{
  heights/.code={
    \def\pgf@tempb{}%
    \foreach \qrr@tikz@rs@height[count=\qrr@tikz@count from 1] in {#1}{
      \edef\pgf@tempa{\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/every \pgf@lib@sh@toalpha\qrr@tikz@count\space node part/.append style={height={\qrr@tikz@rs@height}}}}%
      \ifnum\qrr@tikz@count=1\relax % allows to use \nodepart{text} (or not at all for the first part)
        \edef\pgf@tempa{\unexpanded\expandafter{\pgf@tempa}\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/every text node part/.append style={height={\qrr@tikz@rs@height}}}}%
      \fi
      \expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\pgf@tempb\expandafter{\pgf@tempa}
    }
    \pgf@tempb
  },
  height/.code={%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfutil@minipage\expandafter[\expandafter##\expandafter 1\expandafter]\expandafter{\pgfutil@minipage[][#1][c]}% LaTeX only!
  }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{rect/.style={
  draw,
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split parts=9,
  rectangle split part align=center,
  draw,
  font=\ttfamily, % still works
  thick,
  text width=3cm,
  align=center,
  rectangle split part align={center,left,right},
  rectangle split part fill={gray!30, blue!20, blue!15, blue!20,blue!15,blue!15,green!15,green!20,green!30},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \node (stack) [rect] {
    \nodepart[height=1cm]{one}     $\rvdots$
    \nodepart[height=1cm]{two}     $\rvdots$
    \nodepart[height=1.5cm]{three} Argument n
    \nodepart[height=1cm]{four}    $\rvdots$
    \nodepart[height=1.5cm]{five}  Argument 1
    \nodepart[height=1cm]{six}     Return Address
    \nodepart[height=1cm]{seven}   Saved \%ebp
    \nodepart[height=3cm]{eight}   Saved registers, local variables, and temporaries
    \nodepart[height=2cm]{nine}    Argument build area
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,rect/.append style={heights={1cm,1cm,1.5cm,1cm,1.5cm,1cm,1cm,3cm,2cm}}]
  \node (stack) [rect] {
%    \nodepart{text}
     $\rvdots$
    \nodepart{two}  $\rvdots$
    \nodepart{three} Argument n
    \nodepart{four}  $\rvdots$
    \nodepart{five}  Argument 1
    \nodepart{six}   Return Address
    \nodepart{seven} Saved \%ebp
    \nodepart{eight} Saved registers, local variables, and temporaries
    \nodepart{nine}  Argument build area
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you, but not compile on my linux box, maybe I need to install the standalone.cls file.

Comment: @vampire The `standalone` class is not needed for the answer. I have updated the answer with the stand `article` class.

Comment: yeah, it's compiled ok, and the solution is great, thank you so much:)