# How to add partial horizontal lines in horizontally aligned math environments

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, rules

I'm having trouble writing a proof of a theorem in LaTeX, where I need to sum a set of inequalities and continue the proof with this sum.

The problem I have is that I'd like to introduce this step visually like in the following picture:

[image: desired final output]

but I can't get that horizontal line. In this picture, I added it by editing the LaTeX output using an image editor.

I'm using the `align*` environment provided by `amsmath`.

Is there any way for me to do what I want using a horizontally aligned math environment (like `align*`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120287/16967) has the tiny drawback, that the values for `\tleq` has to be found manually. This answer fills the gap.

Package `amsmath` processes its equations twice. In the first run, the widths are measured.
The switch `\ifmeasure@` is true during this measuring phase.
In the second run the equations are actually typeset. Depending on the measured widths of the first run `amsmath` is now able to move the equation number if necessary, for example.

Also environment `alignat*` stores the widths of the cells and calculates the maximal widths of the columns.

After the measuring phase the widths of the columns are available in macro `\maxcolumn@width`. The values are prefixed with `\or` for easy use with `\ifcase`, e.g.:

```
\or 23.1945pt \or 25.221pt \or 10.00002pt \or 12.77773pt \or 54.77959pt \or 62.81717pt \or 74.90263pt \or 0.0pt \or 0.0pt
```

Count register `\column@` holds the current column number.

The following example defines the macro `\tline` that uses these data to draw a line with the width of the current column. In right aligned columns it is placed after the cell contents, in left aligned columns `\tline` should start the cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tline}{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    % first measuring run
  \else
    % second run
    % \typeout{\meaning\maxcolumn@widths}% debug info
    \ifodd\column@
      \expandafter\rlap
    \else
      \expandafter\llap
    \fi
    {% 
      \vrule height-1ex depth \dimexpr1ex+.4pt\relax width
      \ifcase\numexpr\column@+1\expandafter\relax
      \maxcolumn@widths
      \fi
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
a^1 x^\star &\leq b_1 &\quad& \Rightarrow & \delta_1 a^1 x^\star &\leq
\delta_1 b_1 \\
a^2 x^\star &\leq b_2 &&      \Rightarrow & \delta_2 a^2 x^\star &\leq
\delta_2 b_2 \\[-4.5pt]
        &\;\;\vdots   &&  \;\;\vdots      &                  &\;\;\vdots \\
a^m x^\star &\leq b_m &&      \Rightarrow & \delta_m a^m x^\star
\tline&\tline \leq\delta_m b_m \quad (+) \\
&&&& \sum_{1 \leq i \leq m} \delta_i a^i x^\star &\leq \delta_i b_i &
\quad\Rightarrow \delta^t A x^\star \leq \delta^t b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remark:

- The space above `\vdots` is a little large for my taste, macro `\vdots` already adds `6pt` at the top of the dots. Therefore I have reduced it a bit.

### `\cline` in `alignat*` and better vertical centered dots

- An easier solution is `\cline`, it also works in environment `alignat*`, only the space before needs some adjusting.
- `\rvdots` of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112212/16967) (see Qrrbrbirlbel's comment) cheats a little, it reduces the height by `1pt`. The example below defines `\mvdots` that uses `\vcenter` instead of `\vbox` that reduces the asymmetry by participating the descender.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mvdots}{%
  \vcenter{%
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
a^1 x^\star &\leq b_1 &\quad& \Rightarrow & \delta_1 a^1 x^\star &\leq
\delta_1 b_1 \\
a^2 x^\star &\leq b_2 &&      \Rightarrow & \delta_2 a^2 x^\star &\leq
\delta_2 b_2 \\
        &\;\;\mvdots   &&  \;\;\mvdots      &                  &\;\;\mvdots \\
a^m x^\star &\leq b_m &&      \Rightarrow & \delta_m a^m x^\star
& \leq\delta_m b_m \quad (+) \\[-2ex]
\cline{5-6}
&&&&\sum_{1 \leq i \leq m} \delta_i a^i x^\star &\leq \delta_i b_i &
\quad\Rightarrow \delta^t A x^\star \leq \delta^t b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: The definition of `\rvdots` might be useful here too: [How to vertically center the \vdots in this node?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112204)

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek
I accidentally put the `\tline` commands in the wrong line of my code and, when I compiled it, I realized that if the line should go above the summation, its index would be crossed by the added line... (try putting them in the line of the summation)
For the purposes of this question, your answer is great! But what if I needed it in this other scenario?
Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind doing some eye measurements, here's an `alignat` based solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tleq}[2]{\mathrel{
  \llap{\vrule height-1ex depth \dimexpr1ex+0.4pt\relax width #1}
  \rlap{\vrule height-1ex depth \dimexpr1ex+0.4pt\relax width #2}
  {\leq}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
a^1 x^\star &\leq b_1 &\quad& \Rightarrow & \delta_1 a^1 x^\star &\leq \delta_1 b_1 \\
a^2 x^\star &\leq b_2 &&      \Rightarrow & \delta_2 a^2 x^\star &\leq \delta_2 b_2 \\
        &\;\;\vdots   &&  \;\;\vdots      &                  &\;\;\vdots \\
a^m x^\star &\leq b_m &&      \Rightarrow & \delta_m a^m x^\star
&\tleq{5.7em}{6.2em} \delta_m b_m \quad (+) \\
&&&& \sum_{1 \leq i \leq m} \delta_i a^i x^\star &\leq \delta_i b_i &
\quad\Rightarrow \delta^t A x^\star \leq \delta^t b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

I take as a point from which to draw the rule the relation symbol (left edge). This is called `\tleq` and takes as arguments the left and the right lengths of the rule to draw.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following uses an ordinary `array` to obtain the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l@{}>{\quad}c<{\quad}@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{}>{\quad}c<{\quad}@{}l}
    a^1 x^\star &\leq b_1 & \Rightarrow & \delta_1 a^1 x^\star &\leq \delta_1 b_1 \\
    a^2 x^\star &\leq b_2 & \Rightarrow & \delta_2 a^2 x^\star &\leq \delta_2 b_2 \\
    \vdots & & & \vdots \\
    a^m x^\star &\leq b_m & \Rightarrow & \delta_m a^m x^\star &\leq \delta_m b_m \quad (+) \\
    \cline{4-5}
    &&& \displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i \leq m} \delta_i a^i x^\star &\leq \delta_i b_i & 
      \Rightarrow & \delta^t A x^\star \leq \delta^t b
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The interface provided above is very similar to that of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` using a `<LHS> &<rel> <RHS>` interface.

For more adjustments vertically, I would suggest using struts `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` and play around with the value of `<height>`. For example, inserting `\rule{0pt}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}` inside the `\sum`-line provides a decent padding:

[image]

You can find more information in [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).

Answer (score 4):

The `amsmath` environments `align` etc. are built on top of TeX's primitive `\halign`.  In `\halign` you can span multiple columns via the `\multispan` span command, e.g. `\multispan5` for `5` columns:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
  a^1 x^\star &\leqslant b_1 &\quad
    & \implies & \delta_1 a^1 x^\star &\leqslant \delta_1 b_1 \\
  a^2 x^\star &\leqslant b_2 &
    & \implies & \delta_2 a^2 x^\star &\leqslant \delta_2 b_2 \\
  &\vdotswithin{\leqslant}   &
    &\vdotswithin{\implies} & &\vdotswithin{\leqslant} \\
  a^m x^\star &\leqslant b_m &
    & \implies & \delta_m a^m x^\star & \leqslant\delta_m b_m
    \quad (+) \\[-1ex]
  &&
    && \multispan2{\hrulefill} &  \\[-1ex]
  &&
    && \sum_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant m} \delta_i a^i x^\star &\leqslant \delta_i b_i
  & \quad\implies\quad& \delta^t A x^\star \leqslant \delta^t b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

So the rule is produced by a `\multispan2{\hrulefill}` with verical spacing reduced around it by adjusting `\\[...]`.

Other things to note in the above code

- `mathtools`'s command `\vdotswithin` for placing the vertical dots under the relations
- `\implies` for the implication symbols
- `\leqslant` instead of `\leq` for nicer inequalities.