# How can I do this?

Tags: tables

How can I do this?[image]

Tried using% \ begin {tabbing} but o'que more than displeased was the reticence.

Comment: "How can I do this" is very vague and not welcome unless you show/provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Seems as if you need to read something about LaTeX basics. I recommend »[LaTeX for complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)«.

Comment: Since Przemysław Scherwent was able to give an answer that Henfe accepted, the question was obviously not unclear. I had no problem to understand that Henfe was a novice asking for help to set up a table. He even come up with an example code.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge, both in English and in LATEX. @texenthusiast

Comment: @Henfe No worries :). Have a look at [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/15717) and [What are other good resources on-line for information about TeX, LaTeX and friends?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1621/15717)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure which part is important, but it looks like a simple tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
1  & 0,000 & 1,000\\
2 & 0,301 & 2,000 \\
3 & 0,407 & 2,999 \\
$\vdots$ && \\
10 & 1,000 & 1,000 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might find use for the `\rvdots` macro from [How to vertically center the `\vdots` in this node?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112204)