# Vdots are taller than the rest of text

Tags: math-mode, spacing

When I use `\vdots` within the align environment, its size is bigger than of the rest of characters. I want to get rid of the gap (purple colour on the picture below) or somehow move `\vdots` upward (`\vspace{-Xmm}` didn't work at all).

My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A &= B \nonumber\\
      &=  C \nonumber \\
      &=  \vdots \nonumber \\
      &=  Z \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which gives you

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the hack [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112212):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A &= B \nonumber\\
      &=  C \nonumber \\
      &=  \rvdots \nonumber \\
      &=  Z \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine. I'll wait for accepting the answer just in case that someone comes up with simpler solution.