# Reduce the size of vdots inside a table

Tags: tables, formatting, threeparttable

Consider the following table

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered, listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                              
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] 
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand*\TPTnoteLabel[1]{\parbox[b]{19pt}{\hfill#1}}
  \caption{DiD-Matching Schätzer} 
  \label{tab:DiD} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
\toprule
 & Wertschöpfung & Beschäftigung & Gewinnspanne & Exporte \\ 
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Jahresvergleiche: Vorbehandlungsperiode}} \\
\midrule
$t$ \\
2013 & $\hat{\tau}_{1,13}$ &  $\hat{\tau}_{2,13}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{3,13}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{4,13}$\\  
2014 & \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  \\  
2015 &  & \\
2016 &  & \\
2017 & $\hat{\tau}_{1,17}$ &  $\hat{\tau}_{2,17}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{3,17}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{4,17}$\\ 
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Vergleich: Aggregierte Vorbehandlungsperiode}} \\
\midrule
Phase III & $\hat{\tau}_{1,III}$ &  $\hat{\tau}_{2,III}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{3,III}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{4,III}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}
  \footnotesize
\item Aggregierte Vorbehandlungsperiode: $2003-2004$, Phase III: $2013-2017$.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I am trying to reduce the size of \vdots so there should be additional distance between the table rows due to the size of \vdots

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zlAL.png  Apart from that, could you plase add a sketch of the desired output. At first glance 'reduce the size'  and 'there should be an additional distance'  seem to contradict each other.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Do you want to add a comment,so that I can accept your answer

Comment: @4Leo96: You can define your own `\vdots` like command as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112212/134144 However, I would prefer [CarLaTeX's variant using `\multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471932/134144)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I correctly understand you needs, but why don't use `\multirow`?

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered, listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                              
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] 
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand*\TPTnoteLabel[1]{\parbox[b]{19pt}{\hfill#1}}
  \caption{DiD-Matching Schätzer} 
  \label{tab:DiD} 
\begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
\toprule
 & Wertschöpfung & Beschäftigung & Gewinnspanne & Exporte \\ 
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Jahresvergleiche: Vorbehandlungsperiode}} \\
\midrule
$t$ \\
2013 & $\hat{\tau}_{1,13}$ &  $\hat{\tau}_{2,13}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{3,13}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{4,13}$\\  
2014 & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots}  & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots}  \\  
2015 &  & \\
2016 &  & \\
2017 & $\hat{\tau}_{1,17}$ &  $\hat{\tau}_{2,17}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{3,17}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{4,17}$\\ 
\noalign{\vskip 2mm}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Vergleich: Aggregierte Vorbehandlungsperiode}} \\
\midrule
Phase III & $\hat{\tau}_{1,III}$ &  $\hat{\tau}_{2,III}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{3,III}$ & $\hat{\tau}_{4,III}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}
  \footnotesize
\item Aggregierte Vorbehandlungsperiode: $2003-2004$, Phase III: $2013-2017$.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]